# Spring SqlRowSet getting Clob as String using JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I have a `QUERY` column of type `CLOB` in database.

I am reading it in my program as:

```
SqlRowSet myRowSet = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(this.sqlQuery);

while(myRowSet.next()){
   String currentClobString = myRowSet.getString("QUERY")
   System.out.println(currentClobString);
}
```

But this is giving the below output:

```
javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialClob@7cfe7cfe
```

How can I correct this?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call getObject(String columnLabel) method and use the IOutils from apache commons. This sample code is taken from another SO response.

```
    InputStream in = clobObject.getAsciiStream();
    StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
    IOUtils.copy(in, w);
    String clobAsString = w.toString();
```

Comment: You mean after the following line: Object clobObject = myRowSet.getObject("QUERY")      --- above code ????

Comment: Object queryClob = snapshotQueriesRowSet.getObject("QUERY");
    InputStream in = queryClob.getAsciiStream();   error : getAsciiStream is undefined for type Object..

Comment: SerialClob implements Clob. You need type cast.  Clob clobObject = (Clob)queryClob ;